# hotlinking prevention is not working

Tags: hotlinking

Below is my .htaccess file content to prevent hotlinking. But it is not working at all. What could be the issues ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?exrx.net [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the following line with .*

```
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://i.imgur.com/xxxxxx.jpg [NC,F,L]
```

Also, I placed the .htaccess in the directory with the images I wanted to protect and it seemed to solve my issue.